# EF5 Beta1 DateTime comparison

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, entity-framework-5

I am generating some test data for dates by using a random amount of ticks, but the date i put in seems to have a higher precision than the one I get back. Is this an issue with EF5 or is this something to do with the DateTime vs DateTime2 column types.

EG

Ticks from my generated time: 634074312268196992

Ticks from that time once stored/retrieved via EF: 634074312268200000

Comment: What is the type of your column in the database then?

Comment: datetime, i havent changed it from the default generated by codefirst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned that there are two date types involved then probably the problem is because `datetime` has less precision then `datetime2`

```
date           2007-05-08
smalldatetime  2007-05-08 12:35:00
datetime       2007-05-08 12:35:29.123
datetime2      2007-05-08 12:35:29. 1234567
```

Comment: Its wierd ive never encountered this problem before in EF, as ive never bothered to convert column to datetime2